# Converting ROW_NUMBER column affects performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to know the reason behind why there is a big performance difference when converting a column generated from a ROW_NUMBER window function to a certain data type.

Example :

```
WITH MyCte AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS rownumber, * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
            SELECT 
                j.*, 
                -- Other columns here
            FROM Table j 
                -- Join to other tables here
)

 -- Filter records
SELECT  *
FROM    MyCte
WHERE CONVERT(INT, rownumber) BETWEEN CONVERT(INT, 40000) AND  CONVERT(INT, 40010)
```

---

If i convert `rownumber`column first to INT it will only execute up to 3 secs which is the ideal.

```
WHERE CONVERT(INT, rownumber) BETWEEN CONVERT(INT, 40000) AND  CONVERT(INT, 40010)`
```

---

But if i will not convert it, it will took almost 1 minute to execute the query.

```
WHERE rownumber BETWEEN CONVERT(INT, 40000) AND  CONVERT(INT, 40010)
```

Can anyone to me what is the concept behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER()` function returns value of `bigint` datatype and constant `40000` returns `int`.

Because of this difference in datatypes (yes, even `int` and `bigint`) sql-server can't properly estimate carnality and choose not optimal execution plan.

You should see it on the actual execution plan.

Comment: nice explanation, I haven't think about that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ROW_NUMBER() return BIGINT.
When queries execute, if value of columns incorrect, it will try convert true format value.

See [Predicates](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/36a176c8-005e-4a7d-afc2-68071f33987a/predicate-and-seek-predicate) to learn more information.